# Can hours be added to a Task List?

Tags: date-time, task-list

I am using SharePoint 2013. I created a Task List and am taking advantage of the Start Date, Due Date and Timeline. Instead of a Start Date, Due Date, is there anyway for Hours to be added to  just one Day?

Thanks

[image: List Take Image]

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by changing Date and Time Format of Start Date & Due Date columns.

1. Go to Task list setting.
2. Edit column Start Date/Due Date.
3. Change Date and Time Format from Date only to 'Date & Time'.

After changes made, you will see Hour and minute drop down just beside date pickers of Start Date & Due Date.